# Can someone help me with this awk syntax error

Tags: awk

I'am a bioinformatician but I came from Biology. I'am still learning in the beginning level. But right now I got into an error in awk. The paper show the command, I performed exactly how it is there but still.

In [this paper from Nature protocols](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v7/n3/full/nprot.2012.016.html) there is a command in awk like this for "printing a simple table for each assembly that lists how many transcripts in each assembly are complete matches to known transcripts".

```
$ for i in 'find . -name *.tmap'; do echo $i; awk 'NR  >  1 { s[$3] +  +  } END { \

for (j in s) { print j, s[j] }} ' $i; done;
```

Then, I get an error:

```
find . -name *.tmap
awk: NR  >  1 { s[$3] +  +  } END {
awk:                        ^ syntax error
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to use awk and can't figure out what's causing this error.

Comment: That's guessing, but try removing spaces in `s[$3] +  +` to get `s[$3]++`, it might solve it (separated and concatenated they have different meaning).

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not really sure about what you are trying to do here as I cannot have access to the paper referenced in your question. It seems to be a script which the number of occurrence of the third field of the *.tmap files found recursively from the current directory, to display it at the end. I would suggest to remove the spaces in the "{ s[$3] + + }" like this {s[$3]++}

Comment: You'll be getting shell syntax errors next; you need a `do` after a `for` loop control line and before the `done`.

Comment: @TiagoBruno, you're welcome. I suggest you to accept the answer by @joepd, it provides nice more advanced examples. You might also want to read several top sections of `man awk`, they are quite small, but will make your command-line-fu better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your real question has been answered in the comments (the *increase by one*-operator `++` does not allow spaces), but I would propose to make this thing a bit more performant by only running `gawk` once (BEGINFILE needs `gawk`):

```
gawk '
    FNR>1 { s[$3]++ }
    ENDFILE {
        print FILENAME
        for (j in s) print j, s[j]
        delete s
    }
' $(find . -name '*.tmap')
```

Spawning new PIDs is relatively expensive. If you have a lot of files, you can use `xargs` (assuming you stored the awk prog as `prog.awk` in the current directory):

```
find . -name '*.tmap' -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 --max-args=1000 gawk -f prog.awk
```

Comment: Good thinking. It might be an idea to point out that `ENDFILE` *requires* `GNU awk` and that `$()` *requires* `bash`.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSetchell. ENDFILE and gawk is correct. Command substitution ``$(...)`` is in the POSIX standard and is supported in bash, zsh, mksh and dash.

Comment: Poorly expressed on my part! I was getting at the fact that `$(...)` won't work with standard `sh`. Should be clear to OP and future readers now :-)

Comment: Another thought... should it be `FNR>1`?

Comment: Yes, NR should be FNR. Thanks! ``$()`` is part of POSIX nowadays and all recent enough ``sh``s support it (initially introduced by ``ksh``)